# The int array displays an odd value at the end

Tags: c, arrays, sizeof

I am running this code for teaching purposes about sizeof and displaying array values; everything looks OK with the char array (the last element of the array '0' or NULL is not displayed, the float array displays it as 0.0000... but the char array gives me the last element of 54417138 that looks like an address (hex equivalent 206F6554). I tried to retrieve the content of it assuming it is an address (see the comment part of the code) but got a stack overflow error so I am lost at this moment - any help will be appreciated.

```
     #include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
int i =0;
int j = 0;
int k = 0;

char name[] = {'T','e','o',' ','G','u','g' };
int z = sizeof(name)/sizeof(name[0]);
printf("%d\n", z);
for ( k=0; k <= z; k++) {
    printf("%c", name[k]);
    }
for ( k=0; k <= z; k++) {
    printf("%c", *(name+k));
    }
printf("\n");


int number[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 };
int x = sizeof(number)/sizeof(number[0]);
printf("%d\n", x);
for ( i=0; i <= x; i++) {
    printf("%d\t", number[i]);
    }
for ( i=0; i <= x; i++) {
    printf("%d\t", *(number+i));
    }
printf("\n");

/*int *ptr = 0x206F65540;
    printf("Memory address is: %i\n", ptr);
    printf("Content of that address is: %d\n", *ptr);
    printf("\n");*/

float number1[] = {1.0, 2.5, 3.1234, 10.10};
int y = sizeof(number1)/sizeof(number1[0]);
    printf("%d\n", y);
    for (j=0; j <= y; j++) {
        printf("%f\t", number1[j]);
    }
    for (j=0; j <= y; j++) {
        printf("%f\t", *(number1+ j));
        }
    printf("\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This is the output of the program:
7
Teo Gug Teodor Gug
8
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   544171348   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   544171348
4
1.000000    2.500000    3.123400    10.100000   0.000000    1.000000    2.500000    3.123400    10.100000   0.000000
note the strange value in the display of int array of 544171348*

Comment: You're using `<=` in your `for` loops.  That's bad.  If you have an array of 5 items and you iterate from index 0 up to index 5, the last index (5) is out of bounds.

Comment: Thanks allot just one of those mistakes - smile

Answer (score 4):

You are accessing beyond the end of your arrays with this kind of loop

```
for ( i=0; i <= x; i++) {
```

should be

```
for ( i=0; i < x; i++) {
             ^
             ^
```

as array indices are zero based.

Reading beyond the end of your arrays is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Thanks allot yes I forgot the starting from zero...